# How to setup secure Websocket server using Jetty 11

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, jetty, server-side

I'm new in Jetty and want to create a small test Websocket server with SSL (using Jetty 11).
Found many Jetty 9 based examples, but nothing for Jetty 11.

My test code looks as this:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(int port, SSLContext sslContext) {
        port_ = port;

        server_ = new Server(port_);

        SslContextFactory.Server sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
        sslContextFactory.setSslContext(sslContext);

        HttpConfiguration httpsConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpsConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

        connector_ = new ServerConnector(server_,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,  HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));
        server_.addConnector(connector_);

        var servlet = new JettyWebSocketServlet() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
                factory.addMapping("/", (req, res) -> new WebSocketHandler());
            }
        };
        var handler = new ServletContextHandler();
        handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), "/");
        JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(handler, (context, configurator) ->
        {
        });

        server_.setHandler(handler);
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            server_.start();
            System.out.println("Server started at port " + connector_.getLocalPort());

            server_.join();
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    private int port_;
    private Server server_;
    private ServerConnector connector_;
}
```

An SSL context passed to the constructor is initialized via the keystore and etc.
But when I'm trying to connect to this server I receive "SSL handshake error" at the client side. My client works properly with the same certs & co if I use another Websocket server.

On running the server I see this in the log:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-11.0.15; built: 2023-04-11T18:37:53.775Z; git: 5bc5e562c8d05c5862505aebe5cf83a61bdbcb96; jvm 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7f3b84b8{/,null,AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@5f3a4b84{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:12345}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@149494d8{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:52376}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started Server@5af97850{STARTING}[11.0.15,sto=0] @3110ms
Server started at port 52376
```

So it seems the Websocket servlet is running of the port 12345, but SSL is not enabled for it. From other side, HTTP connector has SSL. I suspect that I'm missing something important.

So my questions are:

- How to enable SSL for Websocket proprly om Jetty 11?
- How it is possible to prevent using random port for HTTP and use single listener port both for the HTTP and Websocket? (actually I need HTTP only to open the Websocket)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are configuring two connectors.

The `server_ = new Server(port_);` is adding the one, and you see in your output as `Started ServerConnector@5f3a4b84{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:12345}`.

And the other is configured with `connector_ = new ServerConnector(...` you see in your output as `Started ServerConnector@149494d8{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:52376}`.

So create the server without specifying a port like `server_ = new Server();`, then set the port on the connector you configured with `connector_.setPort(port_)`.

Comment: Hello Lachlan! Thank you for your answer. You are right: port should be specified in the connector. By changing this I see only one connector in the log. Great! After this change my client was able to connect properly. I also noticed that to authenticate the client it's necessary to add this call: sslContextFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);